# Set the timeout value in Wicket?

Tags: wicket

How do you set the timeout value in Wicket without using the web.xml file; I am not using one.  My project uses bookmarkable pages which I think prevent the session from timing out normally.

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate something like this from inside Wicket instead of the more usual way (through web.xml), you'll need to get hold of the actual HttpSession being used.

I haven't tried to do this, but this [blog entry](http://javathoughts.capesugarbird.com/2007/08/user-configurable-timeout-for-your.html) provides some hints of how to make this connection.

It's a bit old, so some of the details will have changed.  The last comment to the blog provides an alternative to the main content of the blog and looks a bit more recent and more promising.